# Assign Value to record from button click

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, controller-extension, custom-controller

I have two buttons:

```
<apex:form >
    <apex:commandButton styleclass="btn-lg btn-data" value="Vote Up" action="saveUP"/>
    <apex:commandButton styleclass="btn-lg btn-data" value="Vote Down" action="saveDOWN"/>
</apex:form>
```

By clicking "Vote Up", a field `Vote Button`gets assigned a text value "Up", `Vote Total` gets assigned a value of +10 by workflow and `Vote Button` is reset to null by workflow. Vice versa happens with "Vote Down". How do I construct my extension to assign the Up or Down values to `Vote Button` upon clicking?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
I have tried to create a custom button from javascript, but I'm getting an illegal token error.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")} 
var newRecords = [];  
var idLob = new sforce.SObject(“Idea_Lobby__c”);  
idLob.id =”{!Idea_Lobby__c.Id}”;                  
idLob.Vote_Test__c =(’Up‘) ; 
newRecords.push(idLob);            
result = sforce.connection.update(newRecords); 
window.location.reload();
```

Any ideas? Also, once this gets running, can I just call this in a form on my visualforce page using a standard controller or is there more to it?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is a bit broad for this website, can you give some more details; What have you tried so far?  What problem did you specifically run into?

Comment: note, if you just need custom buttons on a detail page, you can solve this problem without VF by using onclick Javascript buttons - many examples available via google

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you consider using a apex:param tag inside the apex:commandbutton tags to pass a string value you want ie 10 or -10 directly into a variable within the controller extension or store in view state as a page parameter. The method that the buttons call can then either retrieve the value stored as a parameter using apexpages.currentpage().getaparameters().get('name of param here'), or alternatively just add the integer.valueOf(name of extension string var here) to your vote total. So two options are readily available.